# need a regular expression that copes with this URL:

Tags: regex

I have a URL from google circles that doesn't get validated by normal regular expressions.   for instance, asp.net provides a standard regular expression to cope with URLS, which is:

```
"http(s)?://([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+(/[\w- ./?%&amp;=]*)?"
```

But when you get a google circles URL:

https://plus.google.com/photos/114197249914471021468/albums/5845982797151575009/5845982803176407170?authkey=CKfNzLrhmenraA#photos/114197249914471021468/albums/5845982797151575009/5845982803176407170?authkey=CKfNzLrhmenraA

it can't cope.

I thought of appending to the end the following expression: `(\?.+)?`
which basically means the URL can have a question mark after it and then any number of characters of any type, but that doesn't work.

The whole expression would be:

```
"[Hh][Tt][Tt][Pp]([Ss])?://([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+(/[\w- ./?%&amp;=]*(\?.+)?)?"
```

For some reason, that doesn't work with complicated URLs either.
Help is appreciated.

Comment: Where did you get the ASP.NET url regex? Can link to any related docs? It seems wrong.

Comment: Also, what exactly are you trying to do with the URLs? Perhaps a regex is not the best approach here.

Comment: the toolbox "regular expression validator" that comes with asp.net has a choice for URLs, and I believe that regex I list is from that validator.  All I'm trying to do is allow the user to enter only valid formats for URLs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the anchors `^` and `$` for the purposes of this test, escaped the `/` because the following is a javascript regex literal, changed the `&amp;`, which had no business being there, to `&;`, removed the space and added `#` to the third character set, and it seems to work okay:

```
/^http(s)?:\/\/([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+(\/[\w.\/?%&;#=-]*)?$/.test( 
    'https://plus.google.com/photos/114197249914471021468/albums/5845982797151575009/5845982803176407170?authkey=CKfNzLrhmenraA#photos/114197249914471021468/albums/5845982797151575009/5845982803176407170?authkey=CKfNzLrhmenraA' )   
// true
```

I also moved the `-` to the end in the third character set, as it should be at the start or end of the set if not specifying a range.

Disclaimer: I do not propose this as good way of validating urls in general, it is just an edited version of the original regex which now works in this specific case.